# Try to Log My query in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I tried to log my each SQL query for laravel 5.2 so for that I found many solutions and I tried below code , but somehow it's not gone a work and not generate the log.

In my **routes.php** - **Code not working**

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query, $bindings, $time, $name) {
        dd("here");
        $data = compact('bindings', 'time', 'name');

        // Format binding data for sql insertion
        foreach ($bindings as $i => $binding) {
            if ($binding instanceof \DateTime) {
                $bindings[$i] = $binding->format('\'Y-m-d H:i:s\'');
            } else if (is_string($binding)) {
                $bindings[$i] = "'$binding'";
            }
        }

        // Insert bindings into query
        $query = str_replace(array('%', '?'), array('%%', '%s'), $query);
        $query = vsprintf($query, $bindings);

        echo $query;

        Log::info('illuminate.query:'. $query);
    });
```

But I tried with the another code sample and it's working fine

code in my **routes.php - working fine**

```
DB::enableQueryLog();

DB::listen(
       function ($sql) {
        // $sql is an object with the properties:
        //  sql: The query
        //  bindings: the sql query variables
        //  time: The execution time for the query
        //  connectionName: The name of the connection

        // To save the executed queries to file:
        // Process the sql and the bindings:
        foreach ($sql->bindings as $i => $binding) {
            if ($binding instanceof \DateTime) {
                $sql->bindings[$i] = $binding->format('\'Y-m-d H:i:s\'');
            } else {
                if (is_string($binding)) {
                    $sql->bindings[$i] = "'$binding'";
                }
            }
        }
        // Insert bindings into query
        $query = str_replace(array('%', '?'), array('%%', '%s'), $sql->sql);
        $query = vsprintf($query, $sql->bindings);
        // Save the query to file
        $logFile = fopen(
            storage_path('logs' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . date('Y-m-d') . '_query.log'),
            'a+'
        );
        fwrite($logFile, date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ': ' . $query . PHP_EOL);
        fclose($logFile);
    }
);
```

**My Question** : why  ***Event::listen('illuminate.query'*** is not working? is there anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: try to use this package https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar, it shows all queries at page and many other staff

Answer (score 4):

Laravel are not firing events as `illuminate.query` anymore. It was changed to classes. https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/41599959d45016f0280d986f758d414fbee81863

Now You have to caught `Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted` event if You want to log sql queries.

You should define your listeners in `EventServiceProvider.php` like so:

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted' =>[
        'App\Listeners\YourListener'
     ],
]
```

Comment: is there any example of listener?

Answer (score 3):

Adding this as an answer for @Hardy Mathew instead of a comment, since comments can't have code formatting:

Example Listener as requested:

```
<?php
namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted;

class QueryExecutedListener
{
    public function handle(QueryExecuted $event)
    {
        dd($event);
    }
}
```

Be sure to add the listener in the `EventServiceProvider` as told by @Giedrius Kiršys